# How can I install a cable jack without a box?

Tags: drywall, coax

I recently had our drywall replaced due to flooding. Our coax cables are now just hanging out of the new wall and I need to install cable jacks.

Is there a way I can mount the coax wall plates to the drywall without an electric box in the wall? I'd rather not cut the drywall if I don't have to. I don't seem to remember the cable company ever doing that either. I've found a few articles mentioning television jack mounting brackets but the local home stores don't seem to have those.

Any tips?!

Comment: The cable company installer will likely as not run cable through the middle of your floor if you let him.  Don't use them as an example.

Answer (score 25):

You could use something like this:
[image]

Cut a hole in the sheetrock according to the template, and when you tighten the screws, the tabs tighten against the back of the sheetrock to hold in place.  You then pull the cable through and use a plate like this:

[image: Screw-On Coax Cable Connector]

Comment: Hah, I was just about to add the first picture to my post. +1 for the old work low voltage box.

Answer (score 12):

They make low voltage wall plate brackets that work well for this purpose. They should be in your local home improvement store with the various connectors for cable, telephone, and network wiring. I've used this one from Leviton. You cut back the drywall to the inner border of the bracket and fold back the tabs into the wall to hold it in the opening. As Edwin says, give the tabs a gentle crimp to make it tight to the drywall:

[image: wall plate bracket]

Comment: Go with this plate.  Use a pair of pliers, gently, to crimp the metal tabs back.  The plastic screw jobs are just a bit more touchy.

Comment: I've used the plastic ones many times (Monoprice sells them for much cheaper than the box stores, if you need a bunch) but something about the metal construction bugs me here. Usually anything metal that is involved with anything electrical would be grounded, but this would not be. Most likely this will never be a problem, but it's conceivable that while doing work, this could cut a high-voltage wire in the wall and become energized.

Comment: Good point @gregmac, though I personally don't install low voltage anywhere that it could mix with high voltage. I always keep a stud between the two.

Comment: @BMitch I prefer to as well, but sometimes it's not possible due to jack placement or where you're able to fish, and sometimes you don't find the high voltage wire till after you've cut the hole.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.homedepot.com/p/CE-TECH-Flexible-Opening-Cable-Wall-Plate-White-5028-WH/203564824#.UhtnuBu1GZM

Same idea as the boxless and does not require cutting and adding the male/female plugs on each end. The continuous cable will also not have any loss of signal from the plugs.

Answer (score -4):

I ended up just getting some plastic anchors that I put in the drywall and then mounted the wall plate directly to those. That seemed like an easier, less messy solution. I know it won't be as strong, but at the end of the day this is only for a cable jack and nothing will be pulling on it.

Thanks so much for the great advice everyone!

Comment: Cables get pulled on.  It's a fact of life.  This is a "Harry Homeowner" solution not a good DIY solution.

Comment: I've seen this done, and by the time I came along to fix it the drywall behind the cover plate looked like Swiss cheese and the cover plate itself was several degrees off square because it was the only angle they had an intact spot to install the anchors.  I'll echo [@TheEvilGreebo](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18340/installing-cable-jack-without-box#comment25810_18360) and recommend you do it right.

Comment: The old-work brackets cost a *dollar*, and take about a *minute* to install. There's just no excuse not to.

Comment: Just the other day I yanked really hard on my cable jack when I was moving the TV. I unplugged tfrom the electrical outlet but I forgot to disconnect the coax.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/105552/27099) demonstrates amply why using anchors (or worse yet, screws without anchors) is a kludge compared to an old work low voltage bracket